# how to simulate a backspace in notepadd ++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have this txt

```
02/02
z/2019
```

i want it to look like this

```
02/02/2019
```

how can i achieve this using notepad++ regular expression function

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the "Extended" syntax only, you don't even need regular expressions.

- Find: \r\nz
- Replace: